# Find the correct mode for a data frame column

Tags: python

I have pandas data frame that includes the following column:

```
df_patient['X'].plot.kde()
```

[image]

When trying to calc the mode of that column `X = df_patient.X.mode()[0]` I'm getting the value: 22.126  (**I got only one mode, even when I tried multimode of statistics package**)

But from the plot histogram I can see that it's not the correct one (it should be around 15)!
[image]

How can I get the correct mode?
I thought about using KDE:

```
X = df_patient[['frame', 'X']]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.2).fit(X)
```

and then to look for the most density cluster and take it's center... but still didn't figure out how to do it!

Comment: I'm not a stats expert, but it seems like you're talking about the median or mean, not the mode, though it's hard to tell without seeing your actual data. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes median can fit, but mean not for sure. Anyway it was strange to me, because in the graph I can see that the most frequent value isn't 22 (based on the counts shown on histogram), seems the mode isn't accurate when there are 2 peaks or something like that. Thanks